# Install LXLE on Lenovo Yoga tablet 2 1051L/F

Tags: 32bit, tablet, wubi, tablet-computer

I have pretty much tried everything I can find, but I haven't manged to get it to work.

I have somehow managed to have [GRUB2](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) available with [WUBI](https://www.lifewire.com/wubi-linux-installation-program-2201175), and have tried that way to start a live USB. Unfortunately, I have no idea how I've managed to get GRUB installed (I've tried for that long and I've forgotten to document things).

In other words, how do I boot from a USB on a [Lenovo Yoga tablet 2 1051L/F](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_yoga_tablet2_10w_1051FL_hmm_en_v1.0_20140916.pdf)  [overview](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/tablets/yoga-series/yoga-tablet-2-1051/parts/PD104222) ?

I do have a USB to micro USB and a USB hub with four ports, a keyboard, and a USB pen drive with LXLE on it, so I do have the hardware.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Neither your User Guide https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_yoga_tablet2_8w_10w_ug_en-us_v1.0_20140916.pdf?linkTrack=PSP:ProductInfo:UserGuide nor the Hardware Manual (link above) shows how to choose to boot from an alternate device. A query has been posted at the Lenovo Forum to ask https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Windows-based-Tablets/How-to-boot-from-Live-USB-on-a-Yoga-tablet-2-1051L-F/td-p/4465102

Answer (score 2):

Get into the BIOS/EFI Firmware Settings:
1) press the up-volume rocker and hold it, then
2) press the big round start button for three seconds.
[image: big round start button]

After the black screen with the white Windows icon and the Lenovo logo clears, choose BIOS Setup from the pale green screen. [image]

Choose Configuration from the Menu Bar and make sure Secure Boot is turned off.
Then choose Exit from the Menu Bar and then pick Save Changes and Exit.

The Yoga will reboot; choose the LiveUSB to boot from.

Comment: Unfortunately, no matter what I do, it continues to boot into Windows. Does it mean anything if I've upgraded to Windows 10 in the past?